# Countdown until mysql query is executed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm redeveloping my online text based MMO, And I'm building a "Travel" Script Where a user clicks where they want to go and it takes X minutes to get there.

The only problem is - Due to limitations of my host, I cannot run 1 cronjob every minute to take away time spent travelling.

Can someone tell me how i could achieve this without using crons? Delaying a query from being run for multiples of 1 minute or so?

Once they set off, A countdown from that moment of X minutes begins, And once their travel time reaches 0 their "location" is set to "destination"

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a javascript like `setTimeout()` check the time and when your condition is met call a script that will make the query.

Comment: are you sure your model design is ok? the time left to destination should not be stored in the database i believe (but maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: so the user sits staring at the screen until the travel time is done?

Comment: @Dagon No, The User Initiates the travel by choosing a destination and then a countdown is initiated, During travel the user will be able to navigate away from that page and the timer will be displayed somewhere else. when the timer reaches 0 a query will be run to move them to their destination and then the location link will appear again.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's what i'm aiming for, how would i go about a query for that?

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP `sleep()` method.

Like `sleep(60);` will result in the script to wait execution for 1 minute.

Do NOT set a script timeout as it wont make any sense.

Comment: Will the user be able to navigate away from the page this is in? for example go from travel.php to chat.php without this being affected?

Comment: Yah. If you decide to redirect them. The delay can only be part of a certain method but not the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a destination time column, set it to when the animals should arrive, and then in the client display a countdown until that time. You could use a query such as

```
select * from arrivals where arrival_time < now();
```

To get a list of animals that have not yet **arrived**, and of course the arrival_time is when they will arrive.